# error PRJ0003 : Error spawning 'cl.exe'

Tags: path, compilation

I converted VS2006 vc++ project to VS2008. When compiling I get the above error. How do i fix it? am I missing this exe ?

Answer (score 16):

There is a bug in the Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition installer. It does not install cl.exe if you only install Visual C++ but not Visual C#. To work around this you have to install Visual C# even if you do not need this.

Comment: +1 Nice one Attila. You saved me a shedload of pointless trawling.

Answer (score 2):

cl.exe is VS2008 (and any other VS) C/C++ compiler, so check for more detailed error message why it cannot be spawned. Be sure you've installed C++ language support when installing VS2008.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your "path" environment variable does not contain the path to the folder where cl.exe is located.

Another possible reason could be that when installing VS2008, you did not select the option to install the Win32 tools (which include the command line compiler).

In any case, you may want to try to repair the installation of VS2008 (by running its setup via Control Panel - Add/Remove Programs), or use its "Add/Remove components" option and add the "Win32 tools" option (under Visual C++ - Visual C++ Tools).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem under Windows 10 and solved it by adding the following paths to the PATH environment variable:

C:\ProgramFilesC\VS2008\Common7\IDE
C:\ProgramFilesC\VS2008\VC\bin\x86_amd64

where C:\ProgramFilesC\VS2008 is the path where I installed Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this error occurs because of path is not correctly set.

Goto Tools>Options>Directories> show directories for > Select Executable files
Here copy the path address from the folder where you installed and paste that path address

G:\Program files\vb (visual basic) 6.0\Visual Basic 6.0\VC98\BIN

then click OK.

This may work for you.

Comment: Single link answers are not great for SO. You should provide a synopsis of the relevant details that address the question at hand.

Comment: Please don't give negative votes without even trying, this method worked for me so i had given this answer

Comment: I searched a solution for VS6 compiler, this hint gave me the right direction

Comment: @Tom Tom Thank you, if it works give the upvote for the answer